# Riot API - Where can I pull Profile Pictures from? Python

Tags: python, discord, riot-games-api

I have a key and it works, I can pull information from the api, and I want to know where exactly do I go to pull a profile picture from so I can post it in a discord message through a bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the riot documents it appears to which image each profile number corresponds
https://developer.riotgames.com/docs/lol

ANSW
http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.15.1/img/profileicon/588.png

you need change the number at the end

144.png....... ETC Program IT